# iOS UrlEncodedFormEntity Equivalent

Tags: android, ios

What is the equivalent code for iOS for this method?

```
public static String post(String url, String json_content) {
    try {
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);

        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("", json_content.toString()));

        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

        HttpResponse response = client.execute(httppost);
        String responseBody = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());

        Log.i("responseBody", responseBody);

        return responseBody;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // Internal Error
    return "ierror";
}
```

Comment: @NaviRamyel Have you got any answer?

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a way to url encode string in **iOS**,
you can use `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:` method of `NSString`.

see more in docs [NSString Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding%3a).